# How to automate the process with expect tool?

Tags: shell, expect

I want to  automate a process with expect :
1.login with a common user in ssh
2.su to root
3.make diretory `/home/test`

```
set user xxxx
set host yyyy
set password1 pass1
set password2 pass2
set timeout 60   
spawn ssh  $user@$host
expect "*assword:*"
send "$password1\r"
spawn  su
expect "*assword:*"
send "$password2\r"
send "mkdir /home/test"
close
```

How to fix the codes to automate my process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. In this case, if `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as `expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session, making the script exits and causing the failure.

Apart from the commands being missed, I see one issue with `su` command. I hope your intention is to create directory with `su` command execution in the remote host, not in local. So, assuming that, you just have to send the command as `su` to the server. Your current code will spawn `su` in the local machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
set user dinesh
set loginpwd welcome
set adminpwd root
set timeout 60
set prompt "#|>|\\\$"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
spawn ssh  $user@$host
expect -nocase "password:"
send "$loginpwd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "su\r"
expect -nocase "password:"
send "$adminpwd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "mkdir /home/test\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "logout\r"
expect eof
```

`eof` will wait for the closure of the ssh session.